# I want to make a 3D map for iOS that is interactive. What software should I use?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, blender

I need to make a 3D map of my school for a school project. I already have a 3D model in blender and I would like to give the user the ability to view around it in 3D space and select their different classes. I was thinking I want to use Swift with Xcode, but I also know a bit of C++. I am also thinking of maybe using Unity3D. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want them to be able to talk around inside of it as if they were a student or something?

Comment: It's, essentially, not possible to do this in iOS-Xcode-Swift.  Just download Unity, you'll have it done in an hour.  FYI Unity uses c#, which is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

It would be super easy to create in Unity and it would be cross-platform so I would go with it.

Comment: Can someone please show me the code to make something rotate in midair? i just need to make it spin around and have the viewer zoom in and out with the finger gestures.

Comment: public Transform target;
 
void Update(){
    transform.LookAt(target);
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
}

This will orbit your camera around target object

Comment: I tried that but there is an error message that shows me error message BCE0004 Ambiguous reference 'LookAt': UnityEngine.Transform.Lookat(UnityEngine.Vector3), UnityEngine.Transform.LookAt(UnityEngine.Transform). How can I fix this? (Sorry for all the questions I'm very new to this)

Comment: Did you declare target as transform?

Answer (score 1):

The Unity3D is a complete game engine with a pretty good computer graphics optimization.
Blender allows you to make the 3D model, so you can import your models into ".obj" or ".blend" file.
Then simply drag'n'drop it into Unity's folder.

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html
```

It'll be imported.
Since you want to make it "interactable", standard CharacterController provides all required functionality, so your player will be able to move around and explore whole school.

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html
```

Even if you want player to fly around, you can download this one asset. It's well documentated and easy to start and use.

```
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28647
```